# Can't understand these technical specifications

Tags: photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I want to submit my logo to a design contest, but I don't understand these technical words. Can someone please help ?

here is what they asked :

**a file with the logo in .ai format (in black&white and in color); options (guidelines) to use the logo on the background of the different color scheme; options to use the logo in advertisement, for souvenirs etc.; proposal of the corporate font, color scheme, style elements.**

I created my logo in photoshop.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

.ai is the Adobe Illustrator vector graphics creating application format, so you can't send your artwork from Photoshop, cause that program is used to create raster graphics.